# Magnetic moment of an electron not parallel to its angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons, magnetism

For the total angular momentum of an electron $\vec{J} = \vec{L} + \vec{S}$, we're often shown a picture like this

[image: angular momentum of an electron]

where I assume that the $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ cones are centred on the $J$ axis because it is $J$ that we measure, and know the projection, $J_z$, of onto the z axis, and thus the uncertainty is in the x and y components of $J$.  (Someone verify this for me?)

Both the spin and orbital angular momentum components have a corresponding contribution to the magnetic moment.  The orbital component is $\vec{\mu}_L = \dfrac{-e}{2mₑ}\vec{L}$, however the spin contributes more strongly, so that $\vec{\mu} = \dfrac{-e}{2mₑ}(\vec{L} + g\vec{S})$, where $g \approx 2$.

Looking at this picture, the vector $\vec{L} + 2\vec{S}$ is not parallel to $\vec{J} = \vec{L} + \vec{S}$, and so the magnetic moment is not parallel to the angular momentum.

So Q1.  Is this true that they're not parallel?

Furthermore, the torque $\vec{\mu} \times \vec{B} $ on the magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ causes the angular momentum to precess in a circle.  But $\vec{L} + 2\vec{S}$ is not parallel to $\vec{J}$, or even generally on the plane containing $\hat{z}$ and $\vec{J}$, so the torque is not perpendicular to the angular momentum and therefore it does not precess in a circle, or even predictably due to the different directions that $\vec{\mu}$ can point around $\vec{J}$.

Q2. What's going on with the precession?  How do we explain circular precession, or what do we expect to happen instead?

If $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ are correlated such that $\vec{\mu}$ is in the $\hat{z}-\vec{J}$ then at least the torque will be perpendicular anyone will still get circular precession, but I see no reason to suppose this.

In fact, if we allow $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ to take any value on those cones, then $\vec{J}$ can have different lengths depending on the relative phase $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ and whether they are more or less parallel, where it should be fixed $\lvert J \rvert = \sqrt{j(j+1)} \hbar$.

Q3. Are the motions of $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ correlated?  How do we explain the fixed length of their sum for a given electronic state?

Comment: Obviously there are not parallel, but slightly in the expectation values : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land%C3%A9_g-factor

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "but slightly in the expectation values".   

 If the magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$ and angular momentum $\vec{J}$ are not parallel, then $\vec{J}$ will not precess in a circle.

Comment: *They're parallel considering the expectation values. Have you read this wiki page? the expectation values of the moment and the total angular momentum are parallel. In this case, the precession is described by a classical expression : the magnetic moment is proportional to the total angular momentum and the factor is  the gyromagnetic factor.